# How to filter Facebook API events by date?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook events API to get public page events. But I want only upcoming events for the page, not those which are already over. So I want to filters them by date. Here is my code:

```
FB.api(
  '/thebikerscafegurgaon/Events',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"category,attending_count,can_guests_invite,cover,description,end_time,declined_count,guest_list_enabled,id,interested_count,is_canceled,is_page_owned,is_viewer_admin,maybe_count,name,noreply_count,owner,parent_group,start_time,ticket_uri,updated_time"},
  function(response) {
      console.log("response",response);
  }
)
```

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer of @Arno. He deserves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is very difficult to find but you can use this, for example, for events:
{event-id}?fields=events.since(2017-05-23).until(2017-05-24)

Comment: Works perfectly. You definitively deserve to be validated.